# How to removed overlapped features?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, network-analyst

I'm using ArcMap 10.1. When I make an attribute based buffer, the result had shown as overlapped. How can I solve this issues?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way eliminate the overlapping regions is within the buffer tool itself.  To illustrate, the image to the left shows overlapping polygon buffers for each line segment.  On the right, I specified Dissolve Type "ALL".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mr.Aaron What is my requirements I need each polygon with attribute.When I used this method, Attribute will be lost right? If I select Dissolved Type all finally I got single polygon only that is the problem for this method.

Comment: @Raj, It is unclear what attributes you are interested in preserving. What attributes are you interested in preserving in the buffers?  Would it be sufficient to preserve the polyline attributes? Could you please update your post with more details?

Comment: I have used with based buffer analysis, I need this field to the purpose of linking non spatial data and cartography purpose, Thats waht I need this filed.

Answer (score 1):

Raj,

You could use Erase (Analysis Tools), with the wider buffered roads (lines) as the erase feature (the dominant feature). This will leave the geometry (shape) of the dominant road alone and 'erase' the portion of the smaller road that overlaps it. You may have to do multiple iterations as you have more than 2 'classes' of road.

Alternatively, if you want them in the same feature class, you could just dissolve them together.

Comment: Dear Tom Please may I know process flow or steps.

Comment: @aaron - great demonstration, however this doesn't maintain his per-road segment attributes.  Raj - For the simplest method, I would export each class (each segment with unique 'attribute' that you specify) to an individual feature class. Then I would run a 'cascading' type erase, where the erase feature is first the highest speed limit (or road width, or whatever your attribute is), and the other feature the next speed limit down. This will maintain all attributes, and allow your main roads to be unbroken, where your smallest roads would always be broken. Explain more if this doesn't suit.